# Electric grid power transformer winding: If it is milliohms, why does 9V DMM show infinite ohms?

Tags: power, transformer, multimeter, testing, winding

When testing large MVA power transformers, like 66kV to 16kV, the winding resistance in DC ohms is milliohms.

It takes a high current supply to do this, then the V is measured across the winding to determine the resistance using Ohm's Law.  If the resistance is less than 1 ohm, why does a 9V digital multimeter show infinite ohms?

I am guessing/assuming that there is a physics explanation.  My guess is that the electric field created in the conductor (winding) from a 9V battery is not enough to polarize the mass of electrons in the primary winding.

It also intrigues/confuses me that I can use a 9V DMM to measure other primary windings on smaller transformers with no problems.  How long is the coil of wire in a primary winding (approximately)?

So why does a 9V DMM yield infinity when the real primary winding resistance is in milliohms?

Comment: Does your meter show '0' or something close to that when you short the pins?

Comment: Yes.  The DMM is working fine, calibrated.  This phenomenon occurrs across several transformers (large MVA) and several calibrated DMM (fluke 87V)

Comment: Copper is a very linear material.  Getting electrons to flow through it isn't like sliding a piece of furniture.  If you've actually got the probes on the right wires, the meter should read milli-ohms (or zero, if the resistance in question is too low for the meter to register).  Fix your technique?

Comment: I understand the theory okay, but this situation is known/observed among several Electrical Power Test technicians, but no one seems to have a good explanation of why this is.

Comment: What happens if you hold the meter in place for a good long time?  You didn't give the KVA rating so my estimate is probably wildly off -- but if the input impedance of the transformer is 10H, it could take a Good Long While before the circuit stabilizes.

Comment: I was considering this too as well.  I have been away from the Electrical Xfrmr world for around a year now, and don't have the same access to the transformer specs.  I did not leave the fluke DMM on for 3 minutes, so the inductance explanations seems good right now.  When testing with a current source, we always rise the current from 0 very slowly, but mostly for safety to not cause any voltage on the secondary winding.  I will look into how many Henries are on the primary windings.

Comment: wild guess: bad contact between the probes and the transformer caused by corrosion?

Comment: @TimWescott After doing some rough calcs to guestimate the inductance of a primary winding (66kV, and assuming no secondary load, excitation currents of 1 amp) and assuming ballpark 500 milli-ohm readings of primary winding resistance, the L/R time constant is the best explanantion.  Thanks for your insight.  I am hoping there is still some EE that is power transformer expert that can confirm this though too.

Comment: Inductance is a good guess, because sampling DMM's may never get a constant current flowing in the coil.  Multi-turn coils also can generate significant voltage from local magnetic fields - enough to saturate the amplifier in the DMM.  Try measuring the AC voltage on a disconnected transformer.

Comment: Keep the answers to the answer section. If you think your guess isn't good enough for an answer, is _definitely_ not good enough for an off-hand comment that can't be edited or properly voted on.

Comment: if @TimWescott wants to post an anwer, I'll accept it.  I appreciate everyone's input, thank you for your comments.  I feel I learn the most by challenges that happen in the "real world," or when putting "the book" to "the breadboard."  Thanks to everyone for sharing their knowledge, experience, and passion for our field.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I heard here in the laboratory of the company where I work, this effect is related to the magnetization of the core. It seems to me to make sense, since the core of the large transformer is actually much larger than in distribution transformers.